# Aplicar 2 IDs de acompanhamento do Google Analytics

Tags: javascript

Preciso aplicar 2 IDs de acompanhamento do Google Analytics em um site.
Já gerei o primeiro ID. Estava lendo, que se eu apenas colocar um acima do outro, não vai funcionar.
O que fazer?

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-00000000-00', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

Comment: Os dois ID's vão ser para as mesmas páginas?

Comment: eu já coloquei os dois e da certo sim

Comment: @LINQ sim, irão monitorar o mesmo site e as mesmas páginas.

Comment: @KarlZillner impacta negativamente no resultado final.

Comment: E qual o objetivo  de ter dois ID's?

Comment: @LINQ duas contas distintas irão administrar a mesma conta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segundo o próprio [suporte do Google](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1032400?hl=en) você pode utilizar normalmente, só **não** deve repetir a instancia do arquivo ***ga.js***, isso pode causar conflitos. Você também pode dar um nome para cada ID e utilizar desta forma:

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-00000000-0', 'auto');
ga('create', 'UA-00000000-1', 'auto', 'xyz');
ga('send', 'pageview');
ga('xyz.send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

Repare que o **xyz** é o nome atribuido a instancia do segundo ID, portanto ele utiliza a função **send** de forma diferente na segunda chamada.

Comment: Eu acabei de editar pq algumas aspas estavam erradas, o código dava erro. Agora está corrigido.

Comment: Funcionou dessa forma.